# How to grab the content before and after an email domain like @ using Regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am a beginner with regular expressions. Can anyone please help me to split an email address value which is being entered by the user in the input box. For example, from **example@abc.com** I want to grab "**example**" and "**www.abc.com**" using a Regular expression.
Currently I am using the following auto complete code:

```
var autoCompleteOptions = {
    url: function(phrase) {
      if (phrase.match(/\./)) {
        var newMatch = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(.*)/.exec(phrase);
        phrase = newMatch[1].replace(/\..*/, "");
      }
    },
```

Comment: Input type="email" and phrase.split("@") would be much easier

Comment: @bigless thanks for your response. After splitting the email can i get the values like as below:   var username = parts[0];
var domain = parts[1];

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the email address entered by a user is stored in a variable `email`,  you can use the following code to split the username and domain part.

```js
var email = "example@abc.com";
var match = email.match(/(.*)@(.*)/);
var username = match[1];
var domain = match[2];
```

If you want to prepend `www` at the beginning of the `domain`, add the following line.

`domain = 'www.' + domain;`

Alternatively, you can use the JavaScript `split()` function to implement the same without RegEx.

```js
var email = "example@abc.com";
var parts = email.split('@');
var username = parts[0];
var domain = parts[1];
```

---

### EDIT

Since the username section in the email can get complex, the above solution can fail in certain cases. For complete email validation, complex RegEx need to be used. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/1561791)

However, for the issue that this question raises, a simple solution can be implemented based on the fact that domain names cannon contain `@` symbol.

The below code should work in all the cases.

```
var email = "example@abc.com";
var parts = email.split('@');
//The last part will be the domain
var domain = parts[parts.length - 1];
//Now, remove last part
parts.pop();
//Everything else will be username
var username = parts.join('@');
```

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that this does not work for all valid emails. For example : `"email@"@example.com`. If you don't believe me look at other pages on Stackoverflow about the crazy email spec.

Comment: @Greenbeard Yes, I agree.. There are many cases where this solution might fail theoretically. But the fact is most major email providers doesn't allow such special characters in their email id. On new browsers, even `<input type="email">` doesn't consider your example as valid.

Comment: @Victor See the updated code. It should work in every scenario.